# MariaDB: Shutdown right after start

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So when i try to start mariadb this happens:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

systemctl status mariadb.service shows this:

```
    * mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2019-02-18 10:11:09 UTC; 4min 1s ago
  Process: 779 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 692 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]
  Process: 690 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 689 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 779 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 18 10:09:36 vps-zap348646-1 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Feb 18 10:09:37 vps-zap348646-1 mysqld[779]: 2019-02-18 10:09:37 140439143227328 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.29-MariaDB-6ubuntu2) starting as process
Feb 18 10:11:07 vps-zap348646-1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Feb 18 10:11:09 vps-zap348646-1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 18 10:11:09 vps-zap348646-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
```

journalctl -xe shows this:

```
Feb 18 10:17:09 vps-zap348646-1 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mariadb.service has begun starting up.
Feb 18 10:17:10 vps-zap348646-1 mysqld[940]: 2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.29-MariaDB-6ubuntu2)
Feb 18 10:18:39 vps-zap348646-1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Feb 18 10:18:41 vps-zap348646-1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 18 10:18:41 vps-zap348646-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
```

And finally error.log in mysql:

```
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-82.2 started; log sequence number 103241    029
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139825235617536 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2019-02-18 10:17:10 139827003494336 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.29-MariaDB-6ubuntu2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Ubuntu 18.10
2019-02-18 10:18:39 139827002763008 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

2019-02-18 10:18:39 139827002763008 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2019-02-18 10:18:39 139825283266304 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2019-02-18 10:18:39 139827002763008 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2019-02-18 10:18:39 139827002763008 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
2019-02-18 10:18:41 139827002763008 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 103241039
2019-02-18 10:18:41 139827002763008 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Either I am blind or there just isn't any error and mariadb is just not working.
Maybe one of you guys have an idea. Thanks.

Edit:

I found a "solution" for now, mariadb is shutting down because of a timeout when starting, so for now I set the timeout to 0. For now this solution is enough but there must be a real solution.

Comment: Is the port 3306 available? Maybe you could check, if some other application is listening on this port.

Comment: Port is available, as mentioned in my edit, mariadb is starting and shutting down again because of a timeout while starting.
Now, by setting the timeout to 0 it won't shut down anymore but this not a "real" solution, or?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that since 10.1.10, MariaDB uses systemd to start the service. The /etc/init.d/mysql script is no longer used, so MYSQLD_STARTUP_TIMEOUT has no effect.

You need to find your mariadb.service file. In our case, it did not contain a timeout so the MariaDB default was being used. Just add `/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/override.conf` file, and put in it:

```
[Service]
TimeoutStartSec = 0
```

In the [Service] section, and it will never time out. After create the file:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl restart mysql.service
```